# HtmlHelper does not contain a definition for "Kendo"? MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-asp.net-mvc

i have this line of code in my View:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
```

sadly "Kendo" is underlined red. and says it's missing an assembly or a refrence to this.
what i have tried so far:

View_web.config:

```
 <namespaces>

    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="Kendo.Mvc.UI" />
    <add namespace="Project" />

  </namespaces>
```

installed Kendo.mvc using the Nuget.

Link to image of references:
https://www.screencast.com/t/fpzvGfAigkWu

added scripts in my View:

```
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>
```

ErrorMessage from Runtime:

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1759  Cannot embed interop types from assembly 'Kendo.Mvc, Version=2016.2.616.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it is missing either the 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ImportedFromTypeLibAttribute' attribute or the 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.PrimaryInteropAssemblyAttribute'
```

Any advices for what i've been missing or doing wrong?
Sorry for my English.

Best Regards
Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: When you open the page in runtime, does it still throw the error? I sometimes notice that it looks like an error in Razor, but when I look at it in runtime there's no problem.

Comment: did you import the namespace for `Kendo` in your `controller`?

Comment: Yes it does. I get the  "does not contain a definition for 'Kendo'" Error in Runtime aswell.

Comment: I have "using Kendo.Mvc.UI;" in both my controller and my view to test it out.

Comment: Added the runtime error to the thread.

Comment: The version that is installed is different from the one declared on the web config Version=2016.2.616.0 instead of 2017.2.621

Comment: i've tried to install the 2017.2.621 but ther is only a KendoUiCore, but i think i will give up and make my own multiselect instead ;).